# Sortable.js vs Interactjs Performance

Tags: reactjs, sortablejs, interactjs

My project currently uses interactjs for drag and drop operations and is a bit slow. I wanted to explore other options that can improve the performance overall. Came across sortable.js but could not find any articles on its performance being better or worse than interactjs. If someone has tried both and experienced the real deal, please help with some benchmarking on Drag FPS using both libraries.